# How to insert new child data in Firebase web app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a simple car database app. When a user adds a new car it creates the below JSON data with blank fields for the gallery:

```
{
    "name": "Cars",
    "gallery": [{
        "img": "http://",
        "title": "BMW"
    }, {
        "img": "http://",
        "title": "Lexus"
    }, {
        "img": "http://",
        "title": "Ferrari"
    }],
    "pageId": "23",
    "storeURL": "/app/cars/gallery"
}
```

Now what I want to do in the app is if a user adds a new gallery image it should add new child after the last gallery picture. So after **Ferrari** it should insert a new object. I cannot seem to do this as every tutorial leads to a dead end and also the official Google docs specify that `set()` will replace all data so if you use `update()` it will add and in this case it does not add.

This code deletes all data:

```
function add(){
  var data = [
    {
      title: 'Mercedes',
      img: 'http://'
    }
  ]
  var postData = {
    pageGallery: data
  };
  var updates = {};
  updates['/app/cars/'] = postData;
  firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  console.log('New car added');

}
```

And if I change and add the child:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('gallery').update(updates);
```

It does not do anything to do the data. Please can you help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See this blog post on the many [reasons not use arrays in our Firebase Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Read it now, I'll wait here...

Welcome back. Now that you know why your current approach will lead to a painful time, let's have a look at how you *should* model this data. The blog post already told you about push IDs, which are Firebase's massively scalable, offline-ready approach to array-like collections.

As our [documentation on reading and writing lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists) explains, you can add items to a list by calling `push()`.

So if this creates a car:

```
function addStore(){
  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var storesRef = rootRef.child('app/cars');
  var newStoreRef = storesRef.push();
  newStoreRef.set({
    name: "Cars",
    "pageId": "23",
    "storeURL": "/app/cars/gallery"
  });
}
```

Then to add an image to the gallery of that store:

```
var newCarRef = newStoreRef.child('gallery').push();
newCarRef.set({
  title: 'Mercedes',
  img: 'http://'
})
```

This will add a new car/image to the end of the gallery (creating the gallery if it doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the comment. Very humbled to hear from a real Google developer. Regarding the answer you are correct; I will try to use the Firebase best practices when using keys. Thanks! (I still like the array old school approach however)

Answer (score 3):

**If somebody wants it With Error Handling :**

```
          var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
          var storesRef = rootRef.child('Lorelle/Visitors');
          var newStoreRef = storesRef.push();
          newStoreRef.set($scope.CarModal,
            function(error) {
              //NOTE: this completion has a bug, I need to fix.
              if (error) {
                   console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
                   Materialize.toast('Error: Failed to Submit' + error, 2000);
              } else {
                 console.log("Data saved successfully.");
                 Materialize.toast('Data Submitted, Thank You.', 2000);

                   }
                });
             }
```

Comment: You can replace $scope.CarModal with JSON  object {
    name: "Cars",
    "pageId": "23",
    "storeURL": "/app/cars/gallery"
  } and it would work perfectly. Pure JS is rare this days.