# Data not getting pushed to firebase (inconsistent behaviour)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to push suspect records in the firebase database, everything is working correctly, but the pushing part doesn't seem to be working. It works very rarely, not every time.
Here is the function:

```
async function storeSuspectData() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
var idnumber = document.getElementById("idnumber").value;
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
var crime = document.getElementById("crime").value;
var hypo = document.getElementById("hypo").value;
var gender;

if (document.getElementById("male").checked) {
    gender = 'male';
}
else if (document.getElementById("female").checked) {
    gender = 'female';
}
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("userKey") + ' ' + name + ' ' + height + ' ' + weight + ' ' + idnumber + ' ' + dob + ' ' + gender + ' ' + crime + ' ' + hypo);

console.log('/users/' + sessionStorage.getItem("userKey") + '/suspectList/');

let token = await database.ref('/users/' + sessionStorage.getItem("userKey") + '/suspectList/');

await token.push().set({
    name: name,
    height: height,
    weight: weight,
    idnumber: idnumber,
    dob: dob,
    gender: gender,
    crime: crime,
    hypo: hypo,
});

alert('Record added successfully');
}
```

The last alert statement is not getting executed and data is not being pushed

Here is the database

[image]

I'm also getting this error on console, but I'm not using document.write() anywhere

```
BrowserPollConnection.ts:480 [Violation] Avoid using document.write().
```

The page is getting refreshed when I click the button on which the function is called as the button is a submit button in a form. I get this

```
Navigated to file:///D:/MyPrograms/CredibilityAnalyzer/front-end/pages/selectSuspect.html?name=afs&crime=0&height=1&weight=1&idnumber=1&dob=2021-01-01&hypo=asdf&gender=none
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Credibility Analyzer</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/selectSuspect.css">


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.7.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="../script/form2.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="fillSuspectList()">
    <div class="testbox">
        <form>
            <div class="banner">
                <h1>Credibility Analyzer</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-block">
                <button type="submit" onclick="showInputForm()">Enter new suspect record</button>
                <button type="submit" onclick="showSelectSuspect()">Select suspect</button>
            </div>
            <div class="showInputForm" id="showInputForm" style="display: none;">
                <p>Suspect Information</p>
                <div class="item">
                    <label for="name">Name<span>*</span></label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required />
                </div>
                <div class="btn-block">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="storeSuspectData()">SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976818/how-to-insert-new-child-data-in-firebase-web-app ?

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well especially the form as mentioned by @Frank? I tried the same code (but hard coding the values instead of form) and seems to be working.

Comment: I have added the html now @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works very rarely, not every time.

This typically indicates a race condition. In this case I suspect that your `storeSuspectData` is being called when the user submits a form. If that's the case: the default behavior for a form is to send the data to the server, and then redirect to a different page. So unless your handler function cancels this default behavior, the page will be redirected and this may/will interrupt the write to the database.

The solution for this is to [cancel the default behavior of the form by calling `e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) on the event that triggers it, and returning `false` from the handler.